# Pandas hist how to set bins by slice step

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

For example, there is a dataset of vacancies with salary mentioned, so I want to make a histogram showing the distribution of salaries by number of vacancies. I want to organise bins by regular steps, e.g. a new bin every 50000 "money". I can write them directly, like in documentation:
`df['salary'].hist(bins=(50000, 100000, 150000, 200000, 250000))` and so on, but with dataset values up to 2000000 the line will be hell long. I think it would be elegant to organise bins using a slice step ([::x]), but I have no idea how.
Humbly asking the community for their ideas and insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about `bins=[bin for bin in range(0, 2000000, 50000)]`

to calculate the max use

```
[bin for bin in range(0, df['salary'].max()+50000, 50000)]
```

Comment: But, by the way, I'm interested whether there is a method to do it using slice. Cause I've seen a code with that one somewhere, but can't find it now and check it myself.

Comment: As far as I know, slicing selects every n-th element. So `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])[::3]`gives you `array([ 1,  4,  7, 10])`. Which is not helpful in this case as it would create equal sized bins (same number of elements in every bin), but you want to define the bins by a fixed amount.